# Identificar valor faltando em sequência numérica

Tags: python, python-3.x

Existe um conjunto de cartas numeradas de 1 a N. 
Dentre este conjunto uma carta foi perdida, determine o número da carta perdida baseado nas cartas restantes.

Dado um numero N,Seguido por N-1 valores inteiros representando os numeros das cartas remanescentes,Encontre e imprima o numero da carta perdida.

Exemplo de entrada

```
5
3
5
2
1
```

Exemplo de saida

```
4
```

Bom esse é o exercício, com a ajuda dos comentarios cheguei ao seguinte código

```
num1 = int(input())
conj1 = set(range(1, num1+1))

for i in range(1,num1):
  valores1 = int(input())
  conj2 =
#          "aqui está o problema, quero que o conj2 seja um conjunto 
#           com todos os numeros digitados em valores1 como fazer isso?"

lost = conj1 ^ conj2
```

Comment: Remo, dentre este problema citado, você poderia compartilhar conosco o que já tentou e onde tem dúvida?

Comment: Se vc tem problemas para traduzir do inglês tem um site [Português SE](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/) onde podem te ajudar. Acredite essas traduções automáticas são muito ruims

Comment: Então cara, eu nao tinha me encontrado com um problema como esse antes.
Eu sinceramente não sei por onde começar.
Acredito que o que eu preciso é fala pra ele mapear de 1 a N, e depois imprimir o numero que nao foi inserido nesse intervalo.
mas como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que as cartas numeradas de 1 a N são sequenciais; isto é, um baralho de 5 cartas possuiria as caras 1, 2, 3, 4 e 5, então a solução é trivial utilizando a classe `set` do Python. Basta você definir os dois conjuntos e calcular a diferença entre eles.

O baralho completo pode ser definido como:

```
deck = set(range(1, N+1))
```

Enquanto o baralho descrito pela entrada pode ser definido por:

```
hand = {1, 2, 3, 5, 5}
```

Neste ponto não ficou claro se realmente deveriam ser duas cartas 5 ou se foi erro de digitação na pergunta, mas isso não interferirá na solução. Para determinar a carta perdida, basta procurar pela carta que está em `deck` que não está em `hand`, calculando a diferença entre os dois conjuntos, com o operador `^`:

```
lost_card = deck ^ hand
```

Para este exemplo, o retorno seria `{4}`, indicando que a carta 4 foi perdida.

Comment: Genial anderson

Comment: mas como eu faço pra receber esses valores de entrada e já guarda-los sequencialmente em um conjunto?

Comment: @Remo que informações precisa ler do usuário?

Comment: c tem algum email preu te passar a print do exercicio?
nao sei colar ela aki.
(é um exercicio de loop, for)
Basicamente ele precisa receber um numero N que será o numero total de cartas, e um N-1 numero de variaveis, e dai falar a que faltou.

Comment: @Remo entendi, mas faz o seguinte: tente resolver com as informações passadas pelas respostas e, se ainda não conseguir, edite a pergunta e adicione o código que fez. Com isso iremos conseguir ajudar melhor exatamente onde está com dificuldade.

Answer (score 1):

Baseando-me na excelente sugestão do [Anderson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/299836/3635), no entanto ao invés de pensar no numero de cartas fixo a ideia é ver a carta de maior valor, supondo que isso seja um exercício baseado em algo que irá evoluir, como mais cartas ou até "naipes"

Então usaria a função [`max(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) ao invés de um numero fixo (ou ao invés de `len()`), assim teria a carta de maior valor, ficaria assim:

```
hand = {1, 2, 3, 5, 5}
higher = max(hand)
deck = set(range(1, higher+1))
lost_cards = deck ^ hand

print(lost_cards)
```

Então supondo que venha a ter algo possível como:

```
hand = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4}
```

Então imagino que se realmente é um conjunto de cartas uma situação de repetir assim poderia ocorrer.

Exemplo no repl: https://repl.it/@brcontainer/missing-cards-in-handpy

Então em uma repetição acabaria que o 4 iria retornar como faltando, assim: `{2, 4}`

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi perfeitamente a questão, mas isso pode ajudar:

```
entrada = [] #lista de valores recuperados
N = -(float('inf')) # diz que N é muito pequeno(Eu não sabia o que usar)

print('informe a entrada:')

        #A quantidade de valores como entrada é definida? usei 5
for i in range(5):
    value = int(input('>'))
    entrada.append(value)
    #Use isso para saber o intervalo máximo
    if value > N:
        N = value

for i in range(1,N):
    #Apos ter capturado o maior valor, percorro todos os valores de 1 a N
    #Se algum não for encontrado, esse é o valor da carta
    if i not in entrada:
        print(i)
```

Isso vai te dar uma luz (Possivelmente).
bons estudos

Comment: Gostei mano, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma opção, não fiz muitos testes, mas a principio está funcionando

Solicito o tamanho do baralho na entrada e adiciono ele em uma lista, depois "perco" uma carta e por fim verifico a sequencia se está ok

```
from random import randint
cartas = []
n = int(input("Quantas cartas há: "))

for i in range(n):
    cartas.append(i + 1)

perdida = randint(0, n-1)

cartas[perdida] =  "x"

for i in range(n + 1):
    if cartas[i -1] != i:
        carta_perdida =  i
print(cartas)
print("A carta perdida é: ", carta_perdida)
```